# Starting a new activity after 2 hours

Tags: javascript, android, android-activity

I have an android application that displays a toast every hour and then every 2 hours I want a new screen to be displayed which I'm assuming is done by calling a new activity.

The timer im using is a chronometer and this is the code I have so far for it:

```
Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener mChronoListener = new OnChronometerTickListener() { // listens to journey timer to initiate time based events
    int alertTime = 10000;
    int breakTime = 20000;

    public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer arg0) {

        long elapsedTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - arg0.getBase();

        if (elapsedTime > alertTime)
        {
            Toast.makeText(SafeDrive3Activity.this, "HOUR PASSED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            alertTime += alertTime == 10000 ? 10000 : 10000;
        }
        if (elapsedTime > breakTime)
        {   
            //call activity2?
        }

    }
};
```

Basically I want the new screen to display some text, a new timer andm a button so it will need to have a completely different design to the main activity.

I'm not sure what code to put in the if statement above to call a new activity or if thats a valid way of doing it.

With the new activity, do I need to create a new mail.xml file as well?

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: from where you are calling/initializing ..Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener mChronoListener

Comment: In the same activity file as the code above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (elapsedTime > breakTime)
{   
     //call activity2?
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NextActivityToLoad.class));
}
```

Use this an try...

Answer (score 1):

If you have a context, you simply do
context.startActivity(intent);

Make sure the intent you use has the START_TASK flag set.

Comment: I don't have a context at the moment.

Comment: The activity IS the context !